# QGIS Modeller- PostgreSQL execute and load- prevent layers being added to map?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing

I have a model which loads a bunch of PostGIS layers, does some processing, then adds the styled output to the map.

A side effect of the 'PostgreSQL execute and load' algorithm is that it loads those layers into the map (I'm only interested in using them as an input to the tool)

Is there a way to suppress these layers being added to the map or a way to remove them as part of the model?